# How to set gallery with three images at a time that is show same both portrait and landscape mode in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set three by three image in gallery in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635547/how-to-set-three-by-three-image-in-gallery-in-android)

I am new to android. I have to add gallery in my application.This gallery take image from drawable folder by using An Array list And there are two button "Next" and "Previous". Now my question is first display three image from array list of drawable folder then when i press next button, display another three image then so on. And similarly on previous button. That is shown same in both portrait and landscape mode.

Please help....?

Thank you..

this is my code  pls help me....

```
package com.chirag.AppGallery;

import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class ViewAppGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    // take an array of integer type and set its value
    Integer[] mImageIds = { 
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_19,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_20,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_21,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_22, 
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_23,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_24
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_25,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_15,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_16,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_18,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_9,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_10,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_11,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_12,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_26,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_27, 
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_28,
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_29, 
        R.drawable.gallery_photo_30
                };


    private int imageWidth;
    private ImageView leftArrowImageView;
    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;
    private ImageView rightArrowImageView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // take an instance of Gallery

         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


         final ExtendedGallery g = (ExtendedGallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
       //  g.setScrollingEnabled(false);
         MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams)g.getLayoutParams();
         mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels/2 +60 ), mlp.topMargin,
                     mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
        // set adapter to gallery calling ImageAdapter class
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mImageIds));

        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                            ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds [position]);


       if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3)
                   {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                                                                               arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                     arrow_right_enabled));

                  }
         else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                     arrow_left_disabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                      arrow_right_enabled));
                        } 
            else if (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.                                           length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1) 
                  {
                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                        arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                      arrow_right_disabled));

                    }

            }
        });

        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                     selectedImagePosition = pos;

                if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3) 
                {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                          arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                         arrow_right_enabled));

                } 
                else if (selectedImagePosition == 0)

                 {

                    leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                          arrow_left_disabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                           arrow_right_enabled));
                } 
                else if
                 (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.                                          length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1 )
                  {
                    //leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                    rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.                                                                         arrow_right_disabled));

                }


            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        leftArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
        rightArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);

        leftArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (selectedImagePosition > 2) {

                    --selectedImagePosition;
                    --selectedImagePosition;
                    --selectedImagePosition;

                }else if(selectedImagePosition == 2)
                {
                    --selectedImagePosition;
                    --selectedImagePosition;
                }else if(selectedImagePosition == 1)
                {
                    --selectedImagePosition;
                }


                 g.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                //g.scrollBy(20, 0);

                    //leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));



            }
        });

        rightArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {




                if (selectedImagePosition < mImageIds.length-3 ) {
                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                }
                g.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);

            }
        });



    }



    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        // Take variable of type Context and String Array because we
        // get the context and array from called class
        Context c;
        Integer[] ImageIds;
        // Take INT variable for saving background id
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c ,Integer[] imageIds){
            // pass the value to local variable of this class
            this.c = c;
            this.ImageIds = imageIds;

            // get an instance of TypedArray and Retrieve styled attribute
            // information in this Context's theme
            TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryExample);
            // get ResourceId from attr and set it to mGalleryItemBackground
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.GalleryExample_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
          //Give back a previously retrieved StyledAttributes, for later re-use. 
            a.recycle();
        }
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // This will return the length of array

            return ImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Take an ImageView of Context c
            ImageView mImageSelected = new ImageView(c);
            // set ImageView Property

        /*  if (position >= mImageIds.length)
            { 
                position = position % mImageIds.length; 
            }
*/
            mImageSelected.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
            //mImageSelected.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
            mImageSelected.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //mImageSelected.setLayoutParams(new                               Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                mImageSelected.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200,170));

            // return ImageView
            return mImageSelected;
        }


    }


}
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gallery" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_disabled" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <com.chirag.AppGallery.ExtendedGallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spacing="10px" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gallery" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_arrow_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_enabled" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
          android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/gallery_photo_19" />

      </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1519

see in this image and make new folder in res named layout-land and make xml file in it with same name of file in layout. and design this file as you need in landscape mode.
use this code and put to buttons bellow gallery view.

move Gallery on button click as per your need using this code.

```
Gallery gv;
gv.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: thank you jignesh but that is running fine in protraite mode but in landscape mode gallery display all images. i want to show only three images at a time in both landscape mode and protraite mode. once again thank you .

Comment: thank you jignesh but that is not working.